# django form.as_p no longer rendering for seemingly no reason

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

Its one of those. It was working a second ago, with no code changes.

my form in django being rendered by `{{ form.as_p }}` was working and now without any code changes it is not.

Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>Christopher Jakob</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Shipping Choices</h4>
        <form action="{{ request.path }}" method="get">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Show options</button>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <table class="table">
            {% for choice in shipping_choices %}
                {# TODO: show choices here #}
                <tr>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Estimated Arrival Date</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{choice.code}}</td>
                    <td>{{choice.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{choice.shippingprice}}</td>
                    <td>{{choice.shippingdate}}</td>
                </tr>

            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my view:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from countries.models import *
from shipping.helpers.calculate_shipping_helper import calculate_shipping_options

from .forms import ShippingTestForm


class ShippingTestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShippingTestView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        form = ShippingTestForm(
            data=self.request.GET or None
        )
        if form.is_valid():
            subdivision = form.cleaned_data['subdivision']
            subtotal = form.cleaned_data['subtotal']
            choices = calculate_shipping_options(subdivision, subtotal)
            shipping_choices = choices

            context.update({
                'form': form,
                'shipping_choices': shipping_choices
            })
            return context
```

here is the form:

```
from django import forms

from countries.models import Country, Region, Subdivision


class ShippingTestForm(forms.Form):
    region = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Region.objects.all(), required=True)
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), required=True)
    subdivision = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subdivision.objects.all(), required=True)
    subtotal = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, initial=0, required=True)
```

here is the url mapping:

```
url(r'^$', ShippingTestView.as_view()),
```

here is the rendered page without the form:

[rendered page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRlTT.png)

Comment: did you try to empty the browsers cache?

Comment: @Jonas just tired it in a Incognito window with no change. Good idea though

Comment: Is your view `ShippingTestView` triggered at all? How does your url mapping look like

Comment: @Jonas just edited my post to show url mapping

Comment: Django unfortunately hides exceptions. Here is a good article about what you can do: https://adamj.eu/tech/2022/03/30/how-to-make-django-error-for-undefined-template-variables/